# Got error message: 'CalledProcessError: Command' in python?

Tags: python

so I am trying to run a simple emissions modeling program called [InMAP](https://inmap.run/), and have encountered a weird error message just from trying to run the [tutorial](https://inmap.run/blog/2019/04/20/sr/). This is a simple python script. Basically, following the tutorial, the script downloads emissions data for the US, and then outputs the health impacts from these emissions. I followed all the directions exactly, and after running:

```
# This step might take a while.

from sr_util import run_sr # This allows us to use the 'run_sr' function
                           # in the 'sr_util.py' file in this same directory.

output_variables = {
    'TotalPM25':'PrimaryPM25 + pNH4 + pSO4 + pNO3 + SOA',
    'deathsK':'(exp(log(1.06)/10 * TotalPM25) - 1) * TotalPop * 1.0465819687408728 * MortalityRate / 100000 * 1.025229357798165',
    'deathsL':'(exp(log(1.14)/10 * TotalPM25) - 1) * TotalPop * 1.0465819687408728 * MortalityRate / 100000 * 1.025229357798165',
}

resultsISRM = run_sr(emis, model="isrm", emis_units="tons/year", output_variables=output_variables)
```

I get the following error message:

```
CalledProcessError: Command. returning non-zero exit status.
```

I am thinking this is some discrepancy with the version of the program maybe referencing the wrong version? I am trying to learn if this is just an issue without how I have python setup, or if this type of error message means the issue is out of my control and is related to the actual website hosting this program. This should be a straightforward tutorial, so I am wondering if this is an issue with how I might have python set up, or if there is something wrong with the code in the tutorial. I am using the exact code listed in this tutorial.

Comment: Which operating system?  If you look at the code for `sr_util`, it actually downloads an executable from a Github repo and executes that program, passing in your data.  The message means that program returned an error.

Comment: And, by the way, it always downloads a 64-bit executable.

Comment: I had not thought about that. I am using Microsoft Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor. Yes I was wonder if there was something off in the code for `sr_util`. I just could not locate the issue and how to fix the code. I was thinking maybe it could be a discrepancy with the specific version of this program.